# execute method where method names are in a List

Tags: scala, generics

I have a List with all the methods in it example

```
List("method1","method2","method3")
```

and I have the definition for all those methods mentioned in above list

```
def method1(){ //definition}
def method2(){ //definition}
def method3(){ //definition}
```

Instead of specifying those functions to run one by one like below

```
method1()
method2()
method3()
```

I want to loop through `List("method1","method2","method3")` and execute those methods

Comment: Look like x/y, whatever is the "real" goal, there is probably a better/more idiomatic way to do it in Scala (as runtime reflection is generally not recommended)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This would require runtime reflection which is slow, unsafe and insecure. Is the list of methods dynamic or static? if static what is the point? if dynamic, do you have a set of methods that you want to allow call or it could be any method?

Answer (score 3):

If all of the target methods have the same type profile (same argument number/types, same return type) ...

```
def method1() = println("one")
def method2() = println("two")
def method3() = println("three")
```

... then all you need is a `String`-to-method translator.

```
val translate : Map[String,Function0[Unit]] =
  Map("method3" -> method3
     ,"method1" -> method1
     ,"method2" -> method2)
```

usage:

```
List("method1","method2","method3")
  .foreach(translate(_)())
//one
//two
//three
```

Answer (score 2):

If method names are known at compile time you can write a macro

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def executeAll(methodNames: List[String]): Unit = macro executeAllImpl

def executeAllImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(methodNames: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  c.eval(c.Expr[List[String]](c.untypecheck(methodNames)))
    .foldLeft[Tree](q"()")((tree, methodName) => q"$tree; ${TermName(methodName)}()")
}

def method1(): Unit = println(1)
def method2(): Unit = println(2)
def method3(): Unit = println(3)

executeAll(List("method1","method2","method3")) //1 2 3

//Warning:scalac: {
//  {
//    {
//      ();
//      method1()
//    };
//    method2()
//  };
//  method3()
//}
```

or

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def executeAll(methodNames: List[String]): Unit = macro executeAllImpl

def executeAllImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(methodNames: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val calls = c.eval(c.Expr[List[String]](c.untypecheck(methodNames)))
    .map(methodName => q"${TermName(methodName)}()")
  q"..$calls"
}

def method1(): Unit = println(1)
def method2(): Unit = println(2)
def method3(): Unit = println(3)

executeAll(List("method1","method2","method3")) //1 2 3

//Warning:scalac: {
//  method1();
//  method2();
//  method3()
//}
```

(the tree generated is slightly different but result of execution is the same).

Or if method names are known only at runtime you can use either Scala reflection

```
def executeAll(methodNames: List[String]): Unit = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  methodNames.foreach(methodName => {
    val methodSymbol = typeOf[SomeObject.type].decl(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
    runtime.currentMirror.reflect(SomeObject).reflectMethod(methodSymbol)()
  })
}

object SomeObject {
  def method1(): Unit = println(1)
  def method2(): Unit = println(2)
  def method3(): Unit = println(3)
}

val methodNames = List("method1", "method2", "method3")
executeAll(methodNames) //1 2 3
```

or Java reflection

```
def executeAll(methodNames: List[String]): Unit = 
  methodNames.foreach(methodName =>
    SomeObject.getClass.getMethod(methodName).invoke(SomeObject)
  )

object SomeObject {
  def method1(): Unit = println(1)
  def method2(): Unit = println(2)
  def method3(): Unit = println(3)
}

val methodNames = List("method1", "method2", "method3")
executeAll(methodNames) //1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if we have any arguments to the method, any idea on how to pass?

Example:
object SomeObject {
  def method1(arg1:String): Unit = println(1)
  def method2(arg1:String,arg2: String): Unit = println(2)
  def method3(): Unit = println(3)
}

Comment: @ahmed i guess this can be a new question